# Route two specific urls to a different application apache

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, ember.js

I have two applications:

- WordPress multisite application serving all domain traffic
- Ember app serving only /example/path/

The following works to a degree in that ember handles traffic to '/example/path/', but it also handles any other routes thereafter like '/example/path/pretty-wp-page':

```
Alias "/example/path" "/var/www/ember/app/dist"
```

Issue is, I want ember to handle only traffic to '/example/path/' and '/example/path/another-ember-route' and WordPress to handle any other, such as '/example/path/pretty-wp-page'

I tried the following:

```
AliasMatch "/example/path(/|another\-ember\-route)" "/var/www/ember/app/dist"
```

To no avail. Any ideas or suggestions? I've exhausted the possibilities of my skillset, can't see a solution in the apache documentation and Google isn't offering anything either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AliasMatch ^/example/path(?:/another-ember-route)?$ /var/www/ember/app/dist
```

This will work for "/example/path" and "/example/path/another-ember-route" only.

Explanation:

- regex paths should always start with ^ to define the start of the request, otherwise they would be valid for /whatever/example/path
- To specify something "optional" which may or may not be there you use ? in regex
- To group a string you use () so you can make it all optional later with ?
- For correctness sake I added ?: to the parenthesis which makes it a "non-capturing group" since you are not using it afterwards, but it is really not necessary to include it.
- Dashes "-" do not need to be escaped
- The $ at the end indicates the termination, nothing after any of those will match, if you remove it, it will match /example/path/whatever.